# Bluetooth SDP Secure and Insecure

Tags: android, security, bluetooth, sdp

What is the difference between an insecure and a secure connection? My bluetoothapp isnt working that well and so i thought about this.
In the Chat example they are using both secure and insecure http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

In my app I am just using an insecure connection and i get this exception every time I want to connect on my connecting device:

BluetoothChatService Socket Type: nullaccept() failed 
BluetoothChatService java.io.IOException: Operation Canceled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insecure is used when you don't want the user to be involved in any authentication process. Depending on the Bluetooth version of the devices involved it might result in creating a link without authentication or creating a link with authentication and encryption but created using secure simple pairing (available in latest Bluetooth 2.1 and above versions) just works model.